# Summarise data on a separate worksheet depending on conditional format

Tags: excel, excel-2010, conditional-formatting, summary

I have several worksheets where one column has conditional formatting. It is the same column in each sheet. What I am trying to achieve is place all the rows in each worksheet where 'column I' is red on to a separate summary worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a once-off type requirement (question is not tagged VBA) the simplest way would be to filter each sheet by colour and copy the results to a new sheet.